# Como faço para ligar para um número de telefone direito do meu aplicativo ANGULAR JS E IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Eu tenho um aplicativo Ionic + Angular Js que recebe os dados do banco e nesses meus dados tem o número de telefone como eu faço ao clicar nele chama direto do meu aplicativo . Agradeço quem poder me ajudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplesmente utilize o moniker de protocolo `tel:` em um element `href`. Exemplo:

```
<a href="tel:+6494461709">61709</a>
```

Comment: Valeuuuu manoooo....

Comment: @Dan100 Sem problema! se tiver mais alguma dúvida é só perguntar. =)